# IdentityServer4 discoveryDocument returns 404

Tags: asp.net-web-api, identityserver4

I'm following this tutorial to setup Ids4, my steps were the same as the video but I'm getting a 404 when I navigate to `https://localhost:5443/.well-known/openid-configuration`.
Things I did :

- created a new Web APP
  -added the IdentityServer4 nuget package
  -edited the startup as follows:

public class Startup
{

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddIdentityServer()
            .AddInMemoryClients(new List<Client>())
            .AddInMemoryIdentityResources(new List<IdentityResource>())
            .AddInMemoryApiResources(new List<ApiResource>())
            .AddInMemoryApiScopes(new List<ApiScope>())
            .AddTestUsers(new List<TestUser>())
            .AddDeveloperSigningCredential();
        
        services.AddControllersWithViews();
      
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        app.UseIdentityServer();
        app.UseAuthentication();
       

        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseRouting();
        app.UseAuthorization();
        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints => endpoints.MapDefaultControllerRoute());
    }
}
```

}

If I navigate to localhost, it displays a hello world as it should, but the discovery document returns a  404. Any ideas as to why?

Answer (score 1):

The order of your middlewares is incorrect. [Here's how it should be](https://github.com/PieterjanDeClippel/SSO/blob/master/Central/Sso.Central/Startup.cs#L65)

Also, to determine what's going wrong, you must check for errors in the Visual Studio **Output** window